# Converting a List To Dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary

I have following classes:

```
public class Header
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    ....
}
public class Item
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public int HeaderId { get; set; } //FK
   public int ItemSequence  { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; } 
   ...
}
```

`Header` and `Item` have a one-to-many relation(each `Header` has many `Items`

I have following `Items`:

```
{{Id=1, HeaderId=1, ItemSequence  =1, Value="A"},
 {Id=2, HeaderId=1, ItemSequence  =2, Value="B"},
 {Id=3, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =1, Value="C"},
 {Id=4, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =2, Value="D"},
 {Id=5, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =3, Value="B"}}
```

I want to write a query to find a dictionary, the key is first `ItemSequence` of each `Header`(`ItemSequence` = 1) and value is other `ItemSequence`s values, in the other word I want to achieve following result:

```
 Key: {HeaderId=1, ItemSequence  =1} , Values : {"A","B"}
 Key: {HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =1} , Values : {"C","D","B"}
```

I wrote following query:

```
var result = ctx.Headers
                .SelectMany(x => x.Items
                                  .Select(t => new { t.Id,t.ItemSequence,t.HeaderId}))
                                  .?
```

which code I should use instead `?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var result =
   ctx
   .Headers
   .ToDictionary(          
      header => new {
         header.Id,
         header.Items.First().ItemSequence
      },
      header =>
         header
         .Items
         .Select(item => item.Value)
         .ToList()
   );
```

Would assume that all headers have at least one item, though.

Thinking about it, it's possible you want the first *ordered* `ItemSequence`, in which case use something like:

```
header.Items.OrderBy(item => item.ItemSequence).First().ItemSequence
```

To ignore headers with no items use:

```
ctx
.Headers
.Where(header => header.Items.Any())
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your desired result, `ItemSequence` always equals 1. I think it's redundant.
You could `group by` HeaderId and convert it to Dictionary like this.

```
        var listItems = new List<Item>()
        {
                new Item(){Id=1, HeaderId=1, ItemSequence  =1, Value="A"},
                new Item(){Id=2, HeaderId=1, ItemSequence  =2, Value="B"},
                new Item(){Id=3, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =1, Value="C"},
                new Item(){Id=4, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =2, Value="D"},
                new Item(){Id=5, HeaderId=2, ItemSequence  =3, Value="B"}
        };

        var lstGroup = (from item in listItems
            group item by item.HeaderId
            into gr
            select new
            {
                HeaderId = gr.Key,
                ItemSequence = 1, // it's redundant, you could remove it...
                ListValue = string.Join(",", gr.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()) // return "A,B",....
            }).ToDictionary(x=>new {x.HeaderId,x.ItemSequence}, x=> x.ListValue);
```